# Slow performance in using storm local cluster

Tags: cloud, bigdata, apache-storm

I'm trying to find out the storm as a pipe line performance.
I ran the following code in local cluster mode:
 http://kaviddiss.com/2013/05/17/how-to-get-started-with-storm-framework-in-5-minutes/

It takes more the 120 seconds to process 100Mb log file, the results are something like 10k tuple/sec.
It looks very poor results.
what is wrong here? does the local cluster mode is much slower than a real cluser?

Comment: Local cluster is really implemented differently. How do you measure processing time? Do you include startup/shutdown process (it might be really time consuming)

Comment: I added static start = System.nanoTime(); in the spout
and another static var in the cleanup function of the bolt